# Modal QMessageBox does not behave like native Windows dialogs

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, messagebox

My application has a dialog that asks the user via a `QMessageBox` whether he wants to discard all changes he made or wants to keep editing. I want this dialog to be modal to the whole application.

I read somewhere that this is the standard behavior for a `QMessageBox`, so I dont have to set it explicitly with something like:

```
mbox.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
```

I wonder why it behaves differently from other modal dialogs in the OS (Windows 7 in my case). On the one hand it functions like it should, i.e. all other input methods in the application are blocked until the user answeres the dialog. However, it doesn't 'blink'* if the user clicks any other window of the application. Is there any way to get Qt to behave like a native Windows dialog?

Thanks in advance!

---

**If you don't know what I mean with this 'blinking': Just open notepad on a Windows OS, type some text and try to close it. A dialog pops up that asks to save, discard or keep editing. Now click somewhere on the editor window -> the border and titlebar of the dialog flashes/blinks a few times.*

Comment: Are you talking about Windows in particular? I can't test it on Win atm, but under Ubuntu it works as it should for me

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Yes I am only talking in the Windows context in this question. As I said it works as it should, but the visual behavior is not the same as in other dialogs of the OS. It is just an optical 'problem' and I just wonder for the sake of the common *look*-and-feel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem arises when the message box has no parent. This works fine for me:

```
QMessageBox box(this);
box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Close);
box.exec();
```

But this does not:

```
QMessageBox box;
box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Close);
box.exec();
```

This makes sense... the message box can't blink unless it knows that its parent was clicked on.

Comment: Great thanks a ton! That was the reason and it totally makes sense. Works great now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that comes into my mind and if you want to deploy your application only on windows you should `#include <windows.h>` and use the **MessageBoxA** API.

Besides that this works great for me in Windows and ubuntu

```
if (QMessageBox::question(this,"Close?","Close this dialog?",QMessageBox::Yes,QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes)
{
    this->close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, including ``windows.h`` is not really an option, as it should stay plattform independent. Also, this is why Qt offers the QMessageBox class after all. I just wondered because Qt GUI elements usually do a very good job looking like native OS elements in any OS... But as a matter of fact the modal message box strangely does not.

Comment: Platform independence is quite easy to achieve with a simple `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32` and `#ifndef Q_OS_WIN32`.

Comment: @Anthony: I know that it is technically possible, but isn't the reason to use a framework like Qt to avoid doing exactly these ``#ifdef``s? I know that Qt can do the expected modal Windows look-and-feel: It does so if I create a ``QDialog`` and set ``setModal(true);``. My question remains: how do I archieve the same effect on a ``QMessageBox`` without making native Windows API calls?

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier the wierd part is that the code i have posted works great on windows 7 too.