# How to make QMessageBox non-modal?

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, messagebox

I'm trying to create a non-modal QMessageBox:

```
QMessageBox msgBox( pParentWindow );
msgBox.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
msgBox.setIcon( QMessageBox::Warning );
msgBox.setText( headerMsg.c_str() );
QAbstractButton *btnCancel =  msgBox.addButton( "Cancel", QMessageBox::RejectRole );
msgBox.exec();
```

(this is a simplified example). The problem is, this is still modal: I can move another (non-parent) dialog, but I can't close it. I also tried:

```
msgBox.setModal(false);
```

but the msgBox still prevents me from closing the other dialog. What am I missing? 
Perhaps the problem is with exec()?

Comment: Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118914/modal-qmessagebox-does-not-behave-like-native-windows-dialogs?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211490/how-to-make-a-non-blocking-non-modal-qmessagebox

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want `nonmodal` (non-blocking) dialog/MessageBox, then yes don't use `exec()`, and just `show()` the messagebox while setting `setModal` as `false`. but if you do that from within a slot/function, the messagebox as declared in your example won't persist because its scope (lifetime) expires by the end of slot/method execution. Therefore you need to extend its lifetime either using a pointer or make it member. For instance, you could have this slot:

```
void MainWindow::popMessageBox()
{
 QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox(pParentWindow);
 msgBox->setIcon( QMessageBox::Warning );
 msgBox->setText(headerMsg.c_str());
 QPushButton *btnCancel =  msgBox->addButton( "Cancel", QMessageBox::RejectRole );
 msgBox->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); // delete pointer after close
 msgBox->setModal(false);
 msgBox->show();
}
```

As of my testing, closing other dialog is possible while the messagebox is show still, but if it prevents you from processing/using other windows until `cancel` is clicked! in that case you would need to start it in separate **thread**, and continue interacting with other window/dialog.